# Admob integration in a single activity application with multiple fragments

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to develop an application which have a single activity. I have achieved all the functionality using multiple fragments. I am showing advertisement using Admob in `OnCreate` of the activity.

Question:
Should I shift Admob code to `OnCreate` of each fragment for more impressions?

Answer (score 1):

No. This might increase impressions but it not increase your revenue (revenue it a function of clicks not impressions) and may well decrease it (you may start getting lower value impressions because your CTR will drop). It will also unnecessarily complicate your code.